# How can I output a property with the DisplayFormat DataFormatString applied in a console app (ideally querying the object by string)?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reflection, razor, console-application

Here's a simplified look at a class I have:

```
public class SalesMixRow
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c0}")]
    public decimal? DelSales { get; set; }
}
```

In a web app razor view, I can get that value as formatted with:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DelSales)
```

I have a console app that needs to output this value as well. How can I output it in a console app without repeating the DataFormatString anywhere?

Update: I like the idea of using reflection, because that solves a question that I was going to ask separately! Here is a complete working sample, where I get a property by string path and output with DisplayFormat if available:

```
void Main()
{
    var model = new SmrDistrictModel
    {
        Title = "DFW",
        SalesMixRow = new SalesMixRow
        {
            DelSales = 500m
        }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(FollowPropertyPath(model, "Title"));
    Console.WriteLine(FollowPropertyPath(model, "SalesMixRow.DelSales"));
}

public static object FollowPropertyPath(object value, string path)
{
    Type currentType = value.GetType();
    DisplayFormatAttribute currentDisplayFormatAttribute;
    string currentDataFormatString = "{0}";

    foreach (string propertyName in path.Split('.'))
    {
        PropertyInfo property = currentType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        currentDisplayFormatAttribute = (DisplayFormatAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayFormatAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
        if (currentDisplayFormatAttribute != null)
        {
            currentDataFormatString = currentDisplayFormatAttribute.DataFormatString;
        }
        value = property.GetValue(value, null);
        currentType = property.PropertyType;
    }
    return string.Format(currentDataFormatString, value);
}

public class SmrDistrictModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public SalesMixRow SalesMixRow { get; set; }
}

public class SalesMixRow
{
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:c0}")]
    public decimal? DelSales { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I believe there is nothing available in the framework that would satisfy your requirement. You may need to write your own processor (another class) that outputs depending on the `DisplayFormat`

Comment: Is the lack of availability a sign that maybe I am taking the wrong approach here? Are these display formats supposed to be web-specific?

Comment: Yeah, kind of. I have added a preferred way as an answer.

Comment: Wow, I just implemented the FollowPropertyPath method (found elsewhere around here) and was looking just for this. StackOverflow and its users are awesome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could retrieve the attribute from the class using reflection.  Then get the format string from the attribute, and apply it using `string.Format`.

```
SalesMixRow instance = new SalesMixRow { DelSales=1.23 };

PropertyInfo prop = typeof(SalesMixRow).GetProperty("DelSales");
var att = (DisplayFormatAttribute)prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayFormatAttribute), true).FirstOrDefault();
if (att != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(att.DataFormatString, instance.DelSales);
}
```

(Note that you'll need to add the assembly `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll`, which contains the `DisplayFormat` attribute.)

Comment: The reflection example happens to be perfect. When I originally asked the question, I was considering the fact that I actually wanted to query it by string a whole separate problem. Your answer led me to a full answer. I have updated the question, tags, and appended a full working sample. It may break somewhere (on my full class for example) but so far so good! I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

The `DisplayFormat` in my experience are meant for MVC applications. For console applications you have got a very sophisticated display formatting system available through `String.Format`. See [this link](http://www.dylanbeattie.net/cheatsheets/dot_net_string_format_cheat_sheet.pdf) for details

In your case, you can write like this

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("0:c0", SalesMixRow.DataSales));
```